# upgrading database

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app already in google store.I am using a builtin database having 3 tables and copying it on first launch of app. Now i want to do upgrade to the app and add another table. Below is my code.

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = context;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist)
    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CKRecordings (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "name TEXT , filepath TEXT , creationDate TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

I want to ask few questions. The above code is not upgrading.

Now if i am new user of the app, do i have to edit the old database and make another CKRecording table and replacing it with current database placed in asset or above code will work for new users too?

Comment: I don't know whether this is suitable to android, but have you had a look at liquibase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

in this statement last argument is database version.. **set it to 2** for new updated APK. so existing user can have newly added table Or Column.

on updated apk onUpgrade will call. and there you can copy database from asset. but than exisiting user will have loss of data.. so best option is to add table dynamically in database.

Comment: on updated apk database do i have to add the table in the database placed in assets folder?

Comment: yes i know that, but i mean to say suppose if you are a new user and u download updated apk. Now will onUpgrade run or i have to place that database table in the database that will be copied when app is run first time?

Comment: If a new user downloads the app (version 2) and runs it for the first time, the onCreate method will be called - not the onUpgrade.  The onCreate method in version 2 of the app should create the version 2 schema, not the version 1 schema.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar follow comment of AndroidGuy... onUpgrade will not call in new user. so database will be copy from asset. so put new database schema in asset folder. and also dynamically create table in onUpgrade for existing user.