# what is the correct way to upgrade sqllite db?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + " ( a INTEGER, b LONG, c TEXT, d TEXT, e DATETIME, f TEXT)";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + " ADD Column f TEXT";

    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE);
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
```

The previous db version was without the "f" field.
Is this the correct way to upgrade the DB?
Do I need onCreate(db) in onUpgrade?

I did this several times and each time I got another exception:
1) table already exists so I added "IF NOT EXISTS"
2) could not read row 0, col 5 error here I lost it....

IS this the correct way to upgrade the db?

I want to keep my data

Comment: uninstall and re-install the app

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14236970/942224

Comment: I want to keep my data besides that, when users reinstall the app on the google play it drops the search rating

Answer (score -13, accepted):

**Caution:** This is a good and working solution but there is are a lot of people who downvote this answer because they have something personal [or because they don't know java's basics(`case` from 10 to 12 are **without `break;`**)](http://ideone.com/FIS7x7)

You have to do something depends on `oldVersion`.

fx: you can have db versions from 10-14, the older then 10 you dont wana support and at every new version you add a new column the code should looks like(newVersion is 14) :

```java
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_CREATE_14 = 
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + 
    " ( a INTEGER, b LONG, c TEXT, d TEXT, e DATETIME, f TEXT, g TEXT, h TEXT, i TEXT)";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_10_11 = 
    "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + " ADD Column f TEXT";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_11_12 = 
    "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + " ADD Column g TEXT";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_12_13 = 
    "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + " ADD Column h TEXT";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_13_14 = 
    "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME + " ADD Column i TEXT";
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_CREATE_14);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch(oldVersion){
            case 10: // from 10 to 11 and go to next case
                db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_10_11);
            case 11: // from 11 to 12 and go to next case
                db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_11_12);
            case 12: // from 12 to 13 and go to next case
                db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_12_13);
            case 13: // from 13 to newVersion
                db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE_13_14);
                break;
            default:
                //not upgratable too old - so we should drop and recreate;
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME  );
                onCreate(db);
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't see any point of down votes without any reasonable comment

Answer (score 0):

You need not call onCreate in onUpgrade. Doing db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_UPGRADE) in enough for update.
Now you should clear data of your application. To do this re-install the app or execute in android shell

```
pm clear your.app.package
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do inside `onUpgrade` method is to drop the table and recreate it. This way, only the data for that particular table will be deleted and not the whole DB data.

```
@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    Log.w("TAG", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
    switch (oldVersion) 
    {
        case 1:
               db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MAIN_NAME);
               db.execSQL(TABLE_MAIN_CREATE);
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Android Documentation:](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29)

> This method is called after the database connection has been configured and after the database schema has been created, upgraded or downgraded as necessary.

**onCreate(db);** is not necessary for upgrade your database.