# Android - On Upgrade For SQLite DataBase

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a application which has a SQLite Database, it's on the play store and recently I've released some updates which includes adding columns to a table in the database

I now want to do another release, which again has another column added to a table, however the problem I'm having is that I don't know if everyone has downloaded the update therefore

If everyone hasn't upgraded if I remove the old changes to database they won't get them and the app will crash

If I leave in the updates and someone who has installed the update tries to update it will say that the column already exists and then won't do the update which is actually needed and the app will crash

I'm guessing that the best thing to do is a try/catch at every alter in the database so that if one fails it will still go to the next one

However I'm wondering if there is a actually 'correct' way of dealing with this issue

Thanks

Comment: you should do something based on `oldVersion` => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078595/what-is-the-correct-way-to-upgrade-sqllite-db/23079187#23079187 <= don't bother about downvotes ... my ironical comments makes some people nuts

Comment: @Selvin your answer is actually right as is the one below, god damn keyboard warriors

Comment: That's how ends leaving the comments under the question/answer which you downvoting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `onUpgrade` you have the **old** and **new** application version. Here you need to decide how to upgrade.

For example, 3 version, v2 has extra column and v3 has also extra column

- from v1 to v3: add both columns
- from v2 to v3: only add latest column needed for v3

Example:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    int upgradeTo = oldVersion + 1;

    while (upgradeTo <= newVersion) {
        switch (upgradeTo) {
            case 1:
                // Add columns
                break;
            case 2:
                // Add more columns
                break;
        }

        upgradeTo++;
    }
}
```