# Manage database versioning on app Update [Android]

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a local `SQLite` database on an Android app and I'm a bit confused on how to manage it when the app gets updated. I need to keep the data stored in the DB whenever I update the app but also I think i'm going to add columns and probably also tables. What's the best practice to do so?

My idea was to check the DB version and if it matches the old version call a method to add the new columns/tables and then upgrade the version, is it the correct approach or there's something else to consider?

Comment: There are lots of way. check Older and Newer version and add column based on that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078595/what-is-the-correct-way-to-upgrade-sqllite-db/23079187#23079187 ... of course script depends on changes (in this example we are just adding column)

Comment: @MD What are the other ways?

Comment: @Selvin ty, that's the approach I was thinking of

Comment: The main problem are the scripts ... fx sqlite do not support column renaming ... so fx you need to rename table, recreate and copy data back from renamed and drop it ... next problem would be change the primary keys ... so, yeah writing migration scripts would be tricky ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_1);
    }
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_2);
    }
     if (oldVersion < 4) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_TEAM_3);
    }
}
```

This is the best way of handling the onUpgrade(). Because users may not update all versions, In that cases this is the best approach.

Comment: It is the same code as in my answer in fact ... but you used `ifs` instead `cases` ... personally i think cases are more readable ...